# how to redirect to another page and move the content

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I have a page with a lots of **elements** in it.

I want to let the user press a button and then page redirected and the contents of the div inserted into the **HTML Editor** which I have.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public property to your source page. Add runat=server and an id to your div.

```
public String HtmlContent
{
    get
    {
        return div.InnerHtml;
    }
}
```

Add virtual path of your source page to your editor page.

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/source.aspx" %>
```

You need to redirect from your source page with using Server.Trasfer method.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Server.Transfer("editor.aspx");
    }
```

Finally in your editor page you can pass the values to your Html Editor.

```
  if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            string innerHtml = PreviousPage.HtmlContent;
        }
```

Comment: i am supposed to use a certian name space like (system.io, system.text, ..etc)

Comment: @Wahtever Just System.Web and System.Web.UI which you should already have.

Comment: @Wahtever are you sure you implemented right? I created a sample application and it's working fine. Can you give specifics? What type of error you get?

Comment: sorry for the late reply: the error was in the editor page **the page does not contain a definition for Htmlcontent** what am i doing wrong .thanks

Comment: You should build your application after adding VirtualPath to your aspx page. Then PrevieousPage will recognize it's public properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like that with [Cross-page posting in ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).

Comment: tried it but didnt work here is what i used:                     `if (Page.PreviousPage != null) {
            TextBox cvDiv = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("cvDiv");
            if (cvDiv != null) {
                mainEditor.Content = cvDiv.Text;
            }
        }`

Comment: it works only for server controls, I think. Can you use `<asp:Panel />` instead of your `<div />` ? <asp:Panel /> render as <div /> on client side so it should't affect the page markup.

Comment: changed the div for a panel but still it didn't work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider storing the data into a database and then just passing the id of the record to the new page as a query parameter; then on your redirected page, read the data out of the database using the id passed in

Comment: im using an html editor to create the page. so it doesnt have data